# Using awk with NSTask

Tags: objective-c, awk, nstask

How would I use this awk command:

```
awk 'NR>1{print $1}' string-to-modify
```

with NSTask? I already tried setting /usr/bin/awk as the launch path, `'NR>1{print $1}'` as an argument, then the string to modify as another argument but all I get is this:

```
/usr/bin/awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>> ' <<< 
/usr/bin/awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove single quotes: `NSTask` doesn't invoque a shell which could interpret them. This is the cause of the error you get.

Second, `awk` takes a filename as last argument, not a string. If you really need NSTask and awk, the shell command would be `echo string | awk ...`, which would involve two NSTask and a NSPipe.

Finally, for string manupulation, use NSString instead, as mentioned by [dreamlax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250344/using-awk-with-nstask/1250472#1250472).

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve? You shouldn't need to launch awk to perform string manipulation.

If you're trying to remove lines from a string, try using something like NSString's [`getLineStart:end:contentsEnd:forRange:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-getLineStart_end_contentsEnd_forRange_) method.